# Index out of range when sending requests in a loop

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I encounter an index out of range error when I try to get the number of contributors of a GitHub project in a loop. After some iterations (which are working perfectly) it just throws that exception. I have no clue why ...

```
    for x in range(100):
        r = requests.get('https://github.com/tipsy/profile-summary-for-github')  
        xpath = '//span[contains(@class, "num") and following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()="contributors"]]/text()'
        contributors_number = int(html.fromstring(r.text).xpath(xpath)[0].strip().replace(',', ''))
        print(contributors_number) # prints the correct number until the exception
```

Here's the exception.

```
----> 4     contributors_number = int(html.fromstring(r.text).xpath(xpath)[0].strip().replace(',', ''))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You are almost certainly being blocked by GitHub. Use their API, don't scrape the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that you're getting a 429 - Too many requests since you're firing requests of one after the other.

You might want to modify your code as such:

```
import time

for index in range(100):
    r = requests.get('https://github.com/tipsy/profile-summary-for-github')  
    xpath = '//span[contains(@class, "num") and following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()="contributors"]]/text()'
    contributors_number = int(html.fromstring(r.text).xpath(xpath)[0].strip().replace(',', ''))
    print(contributors_number)
    time.sleep(3) # Wait a bit before firing of another request
```

Better yet would be:

```
import time

for index in range(100):
    r = requests.get('https://github.com/tipsy/profile-summary-for-github')
    if r.status_code in [200]:  # Check if the request was successful  
        xpath = '//span[contains(@class, "num") and following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()="contributors"]]/text()'
        contributors_number = int(html.fromstring(r.text).xpath(xpath)[0].strip().replace(',', ''))
        print(contributors_number)
    else:
        print("Failed fetching page, status code: " + str(r.status_code))
    time.sleep(3) # Wait a bit before firing of another request
```

Comment: They should be using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) rather than scrape the human-readable side.

Comment: Agreed, but if they need help with understanding why this simple script fails, I doubt they're up to date on using APIs.

Comment: This is the case indeed. I was able to reproduce the issue and got the following response back after a couple of requests: https://jsfiddle.net/48v3rt6o/ (`You have triggered an abuse detection mechanism. Please wait a few minutes before you try again.`)

Comment: @Max: contributor information is available just fine: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/

Comment: @Max: and you can just fetch repository stats: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/

Comment: @Max The first thing you see on @MartijnPieters's link is `Get contributors list with additions, deletions, and commit counts`. Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Max: at any rate, GitHub will not look kindly upon attempts to scrape data from the site whether or not that data is available in the API, and certainly not at the rate you are making requests. They may well block you altogether if you continue.

Comment: @Max: those limitations are there for a reason. Trying to bypass limitations set by GitHub just means they'll limit you from accessing altogether. This is not a game you can win.

Comment: It's related to the original question because it's providing a solution to your problem, that is, stop scraping the website and use the official API.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: they could also be getting a 403 Forbidden; matching the [standard Abuse Rate Limit response for the API side](https://developer.github.com/v3/#abuse-rate-limits). I did reproduce the 429 response, however.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: I'd use [`if r.ok:`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#status-code-lookup), or otherwise test against [`requests.codes.ok`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#status-code-lookup) instead of 200.

Comment: @Max: I've updated my answer to show a) how to get the contributor count (it's a simple `len()` call on the contributors stat) and b) how to honour the rate limit and use the Github ETag conditional response options. Failing that, you should at least use the Retry_After header to pace your requests.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is blocking your repeated requests. Do not scrape sites in quick succession, many website operators actively block too many requests. As a result, the content that is returned no longer matches your XPath query.

You should be using the [REST API that GitHub provides](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to retrieve project stats like the number of contributors, and you should implement some kind of rate limiting. There is no need to retrieve the same number 100 times, contributor counts do not change that rapidly.

API responses [include information on how many requests you can make in a time window](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting), and you can use [conditional requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) to only incur rate limit costs when the data actually has changed:

```
import requests
import time
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlparse

owner, repo = 'tipsy', 'profile-summary-for-github'
github_username = '....'
# token = '....'   # optional Github basic auth token
stats = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/contributors'

with requests.session() as sess:
    # GitHub requests you use your username or appname in the header
    sess.headers['User-Agent'] += ' - {}'.format(github_username)
    # Consider logging in! You'll get more quota
    # sess.auth = (github_username, token)

    # start with the first, move to the last when available, include anonymous
    last_page = stats.format(owner, repo) + '?per_page=100&page=1&anon=true'

    while True:
        r = sess.get(last_page)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.not_found:
            print("No such repo")
            break
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.no_content:
            print("No contributors, repository is empty")
            break
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.accepted:
            print("Stats not yet ready, retrying")
        elif r.status_code == requests.codes.not_modified:
            print("Stats not changed")
        elif r.ok:
            # success! Check for a last page, get that instead of current
            # to get accurate count
            link_last = r.links.get('last', {}).get('url')
            if link_last and r.url != link_last:
                last_page = link_last
            else:
                # this is the last page, report on count
                params = dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(r.url).query))
                page_num = int(params.get('page', '1'))
                per_page = int(params.get('per_page', '100'))
                contributor_count = len(r.json()) + (per_page * (page_num - 1))
                print("Contributor count:", contributor_count)
            # only get us a fresh response next time
            sess.headers['If-None-Match'] = r.headers['ETag']

        # pace ourselves following the rate limit
        window_remaining = int(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset']) - time.time()
        rate_remaining = int(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining'])
        # sleep long enough to honour the rate limit or at least 100 milliseconds
        time.sleep(max(window_remaining / rate_remaining, 0.1))
```

The above uses a requests [session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to handle repeated headers and ensure that you get to reuse connections where possible.

A good library such as [`github3.py`](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (incidentally written by a `requests` core contributor) will take care of most of those details for you.

If you do want to persist on scraping the site directly, you do take a risk that the site operators block you altogether. Try to take some responsibility by not hammering the site continually.

That means that **at the very least**, you should honour the [`Retry-After` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) that GitHub gives you on 429:

```
if not r.ok:
    print("Received a response other that 200 OK:", r.status_code, r.reason)
    retry_after = r.headers.get('Retry-After')
    if retry_after is not None:
        print("Response included a Retry-After:", retry_after)
        time.sleep(int(retry_after))
else:
    # parse OK response
```

Comment: This post is from '13, I'm able to get more than 100 by using the loop in my answer. Nevertheless I ran into the problem that I sent too many requests when I was trying to fetch the total amount of commits of the Linux kernel which has ~800.000 commits. I got blocked after 70 iterations in my while loop. The error message was:
"API rate limit exceeded for [IP] (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)"

Comment: @Max: The code in my answer works for repos I tested. What's the Linux Kernel repository URL?

Comment: @Max: *The history or contributor list is too large to list contributors for this repository via the API."* and a 403 forbidden. Clone that repository and get the count from git directly.

Comment: Alright, in my case it's easier to use the following git command since I download the repositories anyway. But in the near future, the easiest way is probably to use the new GitHub API V4 (https://developer.github.com/v4/).


`git rev-list --all --count`

Comment: @Max: unfortunately, v4 has no contributor info yet, no.

Comment: @Max: you *can* get the commit count with that API though. Even for the Linux repository.

Comment: Yes, but I think GitHub will provide more in the future since V4 is in an early stage.

Answer (score 0):

Now this works perfectly for me while using the API. Probably the cleanest way of doing it.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/valentinxxx/nginxconfig.io/commits?&per_page=100'
response = requests.get(url)
commits = json.loads(response.text)

commits_total = len(commits)
page_number = 1
while(len(commits) == 100):
    page_number += 1
    url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/valentinxxx/nginxconfig.io/commits?&per_page=100'+'&page='+str(page_number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    commits = json.loads(response.text)
    commits_total += len(commits)
```

Comment: Don't guess at the page numbers. Instead, use `response.links['next']['url']` (if set) or go straight to `response.links['last']['url']`.

Comment: Yes, this code is indeed not perfect, but I won't work at it any further.